# merge multi dataframe as one Multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have several dataframes from different websites for exapmle:

```
for website1:
ws1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"title":{"term1":2, "term2":1,"term3":2} , "content":{ "term2":4,"term3":12}}) 

index    title    content
______________________________
term1      2         NaN
term2      1         4
term3      2         12


for website2:
ws2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"title":{"term2":1,"term4":2} , "content":{"term2":12, "term3":1,"term4":6}}) 

index    title    content
______________________________
term2      1         12
term3      NaN       1
term4      2         6
```

I want to merge these dataframes so that the output is a multiindex dataframe. My expected output:

```
            website1             website2
index    title    content     title    content
_________________________________________________
term1      2         NaN        NaN       NaN
term2      1         4          1         12
term3      2         12         NaN       1
term4      NaN       NaN        2         6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use: a dictionary for reference and the `keys` param in [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)`

```
d={'website1':ws1,'website2':ws2}
pd.concat(d.values(),axis=1,sort=False,keys=d.keys())
```

---

```
         website1         website2        
         title content    title content
term1      2.0     NaN      NaN     NaN
term2      1.0     4.0      1.0    12.0
term3      2.0    12.0      NaN     1.0
term4      NaN     NaN      2.0     6.0
​
```

From docs:

> keys : sequence, default None
>   If multiple levels passed, should contain tuples. Construct hierarchical index using the passed keys as the outermost level.